# When using Github pages and React how do you deploy to the homepage, i.e. https://username.github.io/?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

All the examples I see online have you deploy to a subdomain (for example https://username.github.io/my-app). But how do you deploy to the homepage when using React? In my package.json file I have `"homepage": "http://username.github.io/"` and I'm using `npm run deploy` however my site doesn't show up, instead a React information file displays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The repo from memory needs to be username.github.io for it to show under username.github.io and would recommend using gh-pages package, it will optimise the react build for GitHub pages

Comment: If the repo is called `my-app` then it will only be accessible on username.github.io/my-app

Comment: @Thomas__ My repo is named username.github.io. I'll check out the gh-pages package. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I need to do after reading the 'Github Pages' section of this website: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/.